# how to send an email from an Opportunity, with a snapshot of the Opportunity

Tags: email-template

how to send an email from an Opportunity, with a snapshot of the Opportunity.
I have 5 opportunity record types.

Comment: Can you more clear your requirment...

Comment: I have opportunity custom page with 5 record types, my requirement is user able to send an email from opportunity view page. (It should contain some fields of the opportunity like Opportunity Owner,opportunity name,record type,stage ,region, area etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this with almost all standard functionality.

If the email needs to be send out on the push of a button, you could create a custom button on the detail page that sets a checkbox to true 'SendEmail'. the custom button can be onClick Javascript.

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")}

var newRecords = []; 

var o = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity"); 
o.id = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 
o.SendEmail__c = true; 

newRecords.push(o); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
```

Then you create a workflow that checks on this SendEmail__c checkbox and if it is true then as action you send out the email, as a second action (field update) you put this checkbox again to false.

There are still a lot of possibilities, but this will already help you in thinking how this could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by below steps

step 1) Create a button on standard button and button Behavior should be Execute JavaScript.

A) In this button you have to write javascript and remember include below files

```
1) {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/connection.js")} 
2) {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/apex.js")}
```

step 2) You have to write a globle class in which you have to define a webservice method. Call this webservice method from button. When you call this method pass the opportunity id as a parameter and you can write the code in your method for email sending.

Now you need info, how we can call a method from javascript, so below links help you http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/10/calling-apex-method-from-custom-buttom.html http://salesforcesource.blogspot.in/2009/06/triggering-apex-method-with-custom.html
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm